# Why $WS=W^{1/2}SW^{1/2}$ holds fo diagonal matrix W?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am currently reading paper "Graph Sparsification by Effective Resistances" by Daniel A. Spielman and Nikhil Srivastava, on page N7 it says that $\tilde{W}=WS=W^{1/2}SW^{1/2}$, where W is diagonal matrix where $W(e,e)= w_e$. Why is it true that $WS=W^{1/2}SW^{1/2}$?

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: Sorry, will fix it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is claimed in equation $(3)$ on page $7$ that $S$ is defined as a nonnegative diagonal matrix.

All diagonal matrices commute with each other, so you can move $W^{1/2}$ from one side to the other.

Comment: Thank you very much. May I ask one more question from that paper?

Comment: Sure. Just create a new question.

Comment: Thanks, will do it shortly! First, I will try to figure it out myself.

Comment: I have just created a new question!